# Where to ask a question that pertains to Windows and Android?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Where would I ask a question about a Windows based software that can enable me to send SMS via my Android phone which is physically connected to the PC? Would it be here on Super User or on Android SE site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would technically be on-topic for Super User, since it's about a cell phone *as it interacts with  your computer*. However, I suspect you're more likely to get a good answer on Android.SE - or a good answer may already exist even.

Comment: As you said. There is [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone) like that on Android SE and one of the choices, myPhoneExplorer especially, might be what I'm looking for.